# How to launch 2 separate launcher activities with none resuming other

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-launcher

I have 2 launcher activities for 1 app, when 1 activity is started and i launch 2nd activity from launcher it doesn't launch that 2nd activity, instead resumes 1st one.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.fmb.example.LanguageSelectionActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fmb.example.AdminTasksActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/finalize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:taskAffinity=":AdminTasksActivity"` to the second `<activity>`

Comment: Can this be any name instead of "AdminTasksActivity"